# Does clang support bounds checking?

Tags: clang, clang++

if so, how do I turn on? I can't find this in the documentation myself and google didn't provide useful results

e.g,

```
int arr[2];
arr[5] = n;  // runtime error
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. The command-line to enable this is `-fsanitize=address`.

For more information on this, including expected slowdown and why you might be getting link errors, see [Clang's AddressSanitizer Documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html).

Keep in mind the address sanitizer does more than bounds check on stack objects; if that's the only capability you want, I think you can limit it to doing only that by additionally passing `-mllvm -asan-stack`. See [this page on address sanitizer flags](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/Flags) for details.

Answer (score 4):

No. Unfortunately, even with the -fsanitize=address switch, clang does not prevent abusing a pointer to one object to access data of another object. Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   char a[4] = "123";
   char b[4] = "ABC";
   int i, k;
   sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &i);
   k = i + (&b[i] - &a[i]);
   printf("a[%d] = '%c'\n", k, a[k]);
   return 0;
}
```

Save this as badcode.c and compile like this:

```
clang -fsanitize=address badcode.c -o badcode
```

Output of a sample run:

```
$ ./badcode 1
a[17] = 'B'
```

With real bounds checking, a[17] should be detected as an error.